# SubscriberKey and exclusion data extension/ exclusion script

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, exclusion-script, subscriber-key

When we use a Data Extension as an exclusion Data extension or in an exclusion script, is it enough if we only have the "SubscriberKey" field? It is enough to exclude those contacts?
Or should we also add other compulsory fields (like email address for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As every subscriber has an associated Subscriber Key in all Subscribers List, this field is the only required one for an exclusion data extension.

Comment: @Markus_Slabina Thank you. If the field is named differently than SubscriberKey, does SFMC recognize it ? For example, if it is called ContactID ? (if we use the Salesforce ContactID as SubscriberKey for example) Or should the field be nalmed exactly "SubscriberKey" ? Thank you

Comment: You need to make this Data Extension sendable and establish the relationship via the field mapping there.